# c++ builder

Tags: c++builder, c++

Вот у мене есть несколько Memo на форме: Memo1, Memo2, ... Подскажите функцию, с помощью которой я буду иметь доступ к Memo по его индексу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Самое разумное - утрамбовать все Memo в массив и обращаться к ним по индексу. Есть уже [похожий вопрос здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/74165/c-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC). Поглядите примеры кода.

Comment: Почему же это "никак"? А как же FindControl? Да, я понимаю, что это костыль, и так далее. Но все же.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так...

```
int n = 1; // индекс Memo1

for(int  i = 0; i < ComponentCount; i++)
{
    TMemo * Memo ;
    Memo  = dynamic_cast<TMemo *>(Components[i]);
    if(Memo)
    {
        if(Memo ->Name == "Memo" + IntToStr(n))
        {
```

// здесь работай с Memo

```
            break;
        }
    }
}
```